# Printing Page adjustment

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a page like below in Picture 1 but when i click to print that page its not showing properly on the print page.

[image: <code>layout</code>]

**js:**

```
$("#printBtn").click(function(){
    printcontent($("#YearWise").html());
});

function printcontent(content)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', '', '');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><title>Print</title><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(content);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.print();
    return true;
}
```

**html:**

```
<button id="printBtn">Click Print</button>

<div id="YearWise" style="display: none">
       <p style="position: absolute; color: rgb(172, 166, 166); font-family: calibri; font-size: 25px; font-variant: small-caps; font-weight: 100; margin-left: 514px; padding-top: 75px;">Report</p>
       <span style="position: absolute; color: rgb(138, 138, 138); font-family: calibri; font-size: 31px; font-variant: small-caps; margin-left: 466px; padding-top: 42px;">Year Wise</span>

     <div id="main" style="display: block; background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228)" 
     <input id="ChangeYear" class="date-pickerY" style="text-transform:uppercase; font-family: calibri; font-size: 18px; margin-top: -135px; margin-left: 416px; width: 160px; height: 24px; border: 1px solid #717271; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); padding-left: 6px" />
  <img style="margin-left: -32px; margin-top: -134px; cursor: pointer; height: 28px;" src="../../img/Date.png" onClick="OpenDatePicker('ChangeYear')"/>

<ul id="holder" style="height: 785px; width: 1059px; margin-left: -25px; margin-top: -32px; margin-right: -26px; border-radius: 0px;">
<li style="width: 1021px; height: 981px; background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 0px; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 94px;">

 <br>

<div id="YearTable">
     <div class="block">
</div>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I provide a `jsfiddle` for the demo. If you people can help that would be really appreciated.

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsDyX/108/)

**issue now:**

[image: <code>sample picture</code>]

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: @David it should look like the above picture i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your css styles are not included in content, create a css file, write all your inline styles in it and include it as `document.write("<link rel="stylesheet" href="" />");`

This line has a syntax error:

```
mywindow.document.write("<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourpath\style.css" />");
```

change it to this:

```
mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourpath\style.css" />');
```

or do the proper escaping

```
mywindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"yourpath\style.css\" />");
```

OR

simply include a style sheet containing all your inline styles for print content and include it as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="print">
```

If I explain in simple words

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"> // this css will be used on page
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="print"> // this css will be used if you try to print your page
```

Comment: can you tell me please which style.css?

Comment: all your inline css.
make a stylesheet named "style.css" (or whatever) and put all your inline styles in that file and include it as above.

Comment: but i didn't set style for print. I saw some sites there were referring @ media or @ print should i inlcude those in a seperate file?

Comment: those styles are for the content of your page not for printing, remember the write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document. So for printing you are actually writing the HTML expression, so its necessary to add css file to get the desired result of print as you see on your window.

Comment: give a try to it, I remember I faced some what same problem and got it solved with the same.

Comment: thanyou so much. you are good person. I have solved the problem. just a minor issue. my one div is showing little to the right. i want to apply margin-left: -25px but don't know where. If i do in the main file it will effect in the main page also. But i only want to apply on the print part. like above i posted the sample picture.

Comment: include it in style.css for both cases, keeping main.css as your main stylesheet for the page. In second case don't forget to add media="print"

Comment: when i click on the print button, sometimes it load css file and the print format show nicely and sometimes css file not loaded and therefore i get bad print format. do you know why?

Comment: try using this
mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourpath/style.css" />');

Comment: for right now i am using this which is working little better then the previous `        w=window.open();
        w.document.write($('#'+Get_Current_Report_id).html());
        w.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../Extra/Reports Pages/Print.css' media='print'>");
        w.print();
        w.close();`